# IOS Memory Leak From AVFAudio - AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

I try to create a simple project. In this project there are some images and their names and when user push on image, image name is played from mp3 source file and pass next image. However when I pass next image, memory usage is increasing up to 300mb fro each next item. When I check where memory leaks occur by helping instruments,i saw that most of memory leak is caused by AVFAudio library - AVAudioSession.

[image]

Maybe my approach is wrong to play sound. Here my code to play sound:

```
var sound: AVAudioPlayer! 

func playSound(name: String) {

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "mp3")
        let soundURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        do {
            try sound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
    }


@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        playSound(name: "table")
        sound.play()

    }
```

Is my "playing sound" way is wrong? Why this memory leak happen? How to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: All sound file is playing. My url is correct. And yes there is copied file at bundle. Problem is not playing sound. AVAudioSession use to much memory.

Comment: What is the size of your mp3 file?

Comment: Between 15 - 20 Kb. But I use playSound(name:String) function several times in controller.

Comment: You are testing this when running app in simulator or device?

Comment: I am testing on simulator, check memory usage amount at Xcode debug and monitoring and track memory leak from Instruments.

Comment: Please check in device and confirm the memory leaks are same or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested on device and memory usage on device around 30-40mb. So problem is related to testing on simulator. But I don't know why simulator does not release all AVAudioSessions and increase memory usage.